# How to work seamlessly on a virtualenv on different computers?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv folder on google drive that I'd like to work on with computer1 and computer2.

However I'm finding that the virtualenv is almost set up for computer1 only. When I CD to the folder with my virtualenv on computer2, activate the virtualenv, and then run the command

> python --version

I get the error:

> No Python at 'C:\Users\computer1_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe'

Which is a folder on computer1, not computer2.

Additionally, when going through some of the files in venv/Scripts such as the activate.txt file, it has lines such as:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="C:\Users\computer1_user\programming\data_science\python\file\venv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV
```

Which is a folder on computer1.

Basically, how do I set up a virtualenv that can be accessed, changed, and saved from multiple machines? It seems the setup I have now has too many connections to computer1.

Comment: "*…how do I set up a virtualenv that can be accessed, changed, and saved from multiple machines?*" No way. Virtual environments are not portable. You must create a separate virtualenv on every host.

Comment: I see. Guess I'll just use a pip freeze > requirements.txt to setup a similar venv on comptuer2 and just source control it. Thanks

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` Yep, exactly!

Answer (score 0):

If you share a project with others, use a build system, or plan to copy the project to any other location where you need to restore an environment, you need to specify the external packages that the project requires. The recommended approach is to use a requirements.txt file that contains a list of commands for pip that installs the required versions of dependent packages. The most common command is
***pip freeze > requirements.txt***, which records an environment's current package list into requirements.txt.

for more information go to [pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/#cmdoption-r)

If you want to install the dependencies in a virtual environment, create and activate that environment first, then use the Install from requirements.txt command. For more information on creating a virtual environment, see Use virtual environments.